# Software for adding border on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10

Is there an app which can add border on Windows? That app need to run on top of all windows. So that when I am projecting my laptop screen on wall I can see everything surrounded by that border be it a notepad, ppt or movie.

Comment: Not tried (I don't have Windows), but is this the kind of program you are looking for? http://www.howtogeek.com/130138/how-to-change-the-window-border-size-in-windows-8/

Comment: Not clear what you mean exactly. Do you want a (black?) border at the edges of your screen? Can you add a picture of what you want?

Comment: If I understand this request correctly, you're looking for something like GoToMeeting where you can share your screen over the Internet. While sharing, the shared window has a green border. The participants see nothing but the shared window. However, you don't want this for online sharing but for local presentation on the beamer.

Comment: If that's correct, it's a cool request. Not that I knew a software which would solve this task, but I can remember cases where such a software would have been useful. You probably need to define how to deal with the possible resolution mismatch.